# How to install ingenico epayments in Magento 2?

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I am having trouble installing ingenico epayments on magento 2.
The documentation advises to install with composer ([ingenico doc](https://epayments.developer-ingenico.com/documentation/ecommerce-extensions/magento-2/installation-and-configuration/)) but I can not fix the following error after "composer require ingenico/ingenico_epayments_ogn2:3.3.1":

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ingenico/ingenico_epayments_ogn2 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by ingenico/ingenico_epayments_ogn2[3.3.1].
    - ingenico/ingenico_epayments_ogn2 3.3.1 requires ingenico/library-ops-m2 ~3.3.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I also tried to install the module with the magento 2 setup wizard. But the Readiness Check fails for "Check Cron Scripts" and "Check Component Dependency"

I identified the cron that poses problem (update) and when I execute it manually I have this error :
"/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/update/cron.php"

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/update/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/update/cron.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/html/update/cron.php:7
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/update/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/update/cron.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/html/update/cron.php:7
```

It's because the vendor folder is not in the update folder but in the root directory.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Install this module using below way and use a package which has both the folders zip(library and extension)

```
composer config repositories.ingenico artifact /path/to/folder/with/package/
composer require ingenico/ingenico_epayments_ogn2
composer update
```